# Evaluate $\frac{d}{dx}ⁿx$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Evaluate $\frac{d}{dx}ⁿx$ which $ⁿx=x^{x^{x^{...}}}$, total $n$ $x$'s.

I have tried to observe when $n=1,2,3,4,5$, but it's difficult to see the pattern. Can anyone get it? Thank you.

Comment: The derivative is defined recursively. Take logs of both sides and implicitly differentiate.

Comment: A [google search for "differentiation" AND "tetration"](http://www.google.com/search?q=differentiation+tetration) brings up a lot of relevant items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, define $y= ^n\!\!x$. Then
$$\log y=\log ^nx=\log x^{^{n-1}x}=\, ^{n-1}x\log x.$$

Differentiating implicitly, we get
$$\frac{d y}{d x}\frac{1}{y}=\frac{d}{dx}(\, ^{n-1}x)\log x+\, ^{n-1}x\frac{1}{x},$$
from which we see
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\, ^{n}x)=\frac{\, ^{n}x}{x}\left(x\log x\frac{d}{dx}(\, ^{n-1}x)+\, ^{n-1}x\right).$$

For the first few values of $n$, we get

$n=1:\quad\frac{d}{dx}(\, ^{1}x)=\frac{d}{dx}(x)=1$

$n=2:\quad\frac{d}{dx}(\, ^{2}x)=\frac{\, ^{2}x}{x}\left(x\log x\frac{d}{dx}(\, ^{1}x)+\, ^{1}x\right)=x^x(\log x+1)$

$n=3:\quad\frac{d}{dx}(\, ^{3}x)=\frac{\, ^{3}x}{x}\left(x\log x\frac{d}{dx}(\, ^{2}x)+\, ^{2}x\right)=x^{x^x}\left(x^x(\log x+1)\log x+x^{x-1}\right)$

Comment: But your answer still have $\frac{d}{dx}(^{n-1}x)$.

Comment: You have to build up the definitions recursively. This is the only way to get an explicit formulas, like I was doing above. The implicit definition is the only solution for general $n$.